# What does Non-Linearity of Deep Neural Networks means?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

When we say "non-linearity of deep neural networks", what do we actually mean by the term "non-linearity" in this context ?

Also, the purpose of the activation function is to introduce non-linearity into the network. What does this non-linearity means ?
(I am new to Deep learning.)

Comment: This question is better suited for crossvalidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

non-linear means that the output cannot be reproduced from a linear combination of the inputs (which is not the same as output that renders to a straight line--the word for this is affine).

another way to think of it: without a non-linear activation function in the network, a NN, no matter how many layers it had, would behave just like a single-layer perceptron, because summing these layers would give you just another linear function (see definition just above).

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782071/why-must-a-nonlinear-activation-function-be-used-in-a-backpropagation-neural-net)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post answers on obviously off topic / bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)