# Is activation only used for non-linearity ?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Is activation only used for non-linearity or for both problems . I am still confused why do we need activation function and how can it help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why must a nonlinear activation function be used in a backpropagation neural network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782071/why-must-a-nonlinear-activation-function-be-used-in-a-backpropagation-neural-net)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, such a question would be suited for [Stats Stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or the [Data Science Stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), since it is a purely theoretical question, and not directly related to programming (which is what Stackoverflow is for).

Anyways, I am assuming that you are referring to the classes of *linearly separable* and *not linearly separable* problems when you talk about "both problems.
In fact, non-linearity in a function is always used, no matter which kind of problem you are trying to solve with a neural network.The simple reason for non-linearities as activation function is simply the following:

#### Every layer in the network consists of a sequence of linear operations, plus the non-linearity.

Formally - and this is something you might have seen before - you can express the mathemtical operation of a single layer `F` and it's input `h` as:

```
F(h) = Wh + b
```

where `W` represents a matrix of weights, plus a bias `b`. This operation is purely sequential, and for a simple multi-layer perceptron (with `n` layers and without non-linearities), we can write the calculations as follows:

```
y = F_n(F_n-1(F_n-2(...(F_1(x))))
```

which is equivalent to

```
y = W_n W_n-1 W_n-2 ... W_1 x + b_1 + b_2 + ... + b_n
```

Specifically, we note that these are only multiplications and additions, which we can rearrange in any way we like; particularly, [we could aggregate this into one uber-matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearOperator.html) W_p and bias b_p, to rewrite it in a single formula:

```
y = W_p x + b_p
```

This has the same expressive power as the above multi-layer perceptron, but can inherently be modeled by a single layer! (While having much less parameters than before).

Introducing non-linearities to this equation turns the simple "building blocks" `F(h)` into:

```
F(h) = g(Wh + b)
```

Now, the reformulation of a sequence of layers is not possible anymore, and then non-linearity additionally allows us to [approximate any arbitrary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem).

EDIT:
To address another concern of yours ("how does it help?"), I should explicitly mention that not every function is linearly separable, and thus cannot be solved by a purely linear network (i.e. without non-linearities). One classic simple example is the [XOR operator](https://medium.com/@jayeshbahire/the-xor-problem-in-neural-networks-50006411840b).